# Are there any Antipope Saints aside from Hippolytus of Rome?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, saint, canonization, antipope

Have any **antipopes** other than [Antipope Hippolytus of Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolytus_of_Rome) ever been canonized as saints by the Roman Catholic Church?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one other antipope than **Hippolytus of Rome** is considered a saint in the Catholic Church.

The antipope **Felix II** has been given the status of a saint in the Roman Martyrology with a feast day of July 29.

> According to the ["Liber Pontificalis"](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09224a.htm), which may be registering here a reliable tradition, Felix built a church on the via Aurelia. It is well known that on this road was buried a Roman martyr, Felix; hence it seems not improbable that apropos of both there arose a confusion (see [FELIX I](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06029b.htm)) through which the real story of the antipope was lost and he obtained in local Roman history the status of a saint and a confessor. As such he appears in the Roman Martyrology on 29 July. - [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06030a.htm)